# PostSharp NotifyPropertyChanged attribute not working for customized setters

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

Hi I've been trying PostSharp Express for couple weeks. The NotifyPropertyChanged Attribute works fine for default getters and setters, but once I customize my setter, it doesn't although I see the changed value appearing in debugging mode, no data get's refreshed on the screen. Here's my sample model class:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Question
{
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }

    private string _answer;

    public string Answer
    {
        get { return _answer; }
        set
        {
            if (_answer == value) return;
            _answer = value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_answer) && _answer.ToLower().Equals("no"))
                IsNoChecked = true;
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_answer) && _answer.ToLower().Equals("yes"))
                IsYesChecked = true;
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_answer) && _answer.ToLower().Equals("n/a"))
                IsNotApplicableChecked = true;

        }
    }
}
```

The binding works fine for the property **QuestionCode** property.

But here when I change the **Answer** property, in the ViewModel, only on the first occassion it triggers the change, apart from that the changes are not propagated. I have already set the

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay
```

attributes to my control.

**UPDATE:** I use the above class as a list in another class like the one below:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I was forced to implement the conventional INotifyPropertyChangedEvent event for this property alone. Doesn't PostSharp support this behaviour out of the box? or am I missing something here? Please kindly help.

Comment: In our tests of this class the PropertyChanged event is always raised for the Answer property. We tested with the latest builds of PostSharp - 3.1.64 and 4.1.13. What version is used in your project? For the test purpose, you can also subscribe to the event manually and log a property name every time event is raised.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I have updated my question. 

I'm using 4.1.12.0. Actually this 'Question' class is used in the form of Lists in another class called Category, which is also marked with this attribute. Is there a special way to handle property notifications for Lists<T>?

Comment: Normally, you need to use ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T> to be notified of the changes to the collection items.